# Prevent public module variables from being globally accessible

Tags: vb.net

If I have the following code:

```
Public Module MyModule
    Public MyVariable As Integer
End Module
```

VB.NET allows unqualified access to the variable (field) from anywhere in the project, which means I can write the following anywhere in the project<sup>1</sup>:

```
MyVariable = 5
```

Is there any way to disable this behavior on a specific type, such that I can only access the variable via the module name?

```
MyModule.MyVariable = 5
```

NB. I know I can use a standard class, and the `Shared` keyword on all the members:

```
Public Class MyModule
    Public Shared MyVariable
End Class
```

---

<sup>1. If I use `Friend` instead of `Public` on the module, this functionality will only apply to the assembly, not the entire project.</sup>

Comment: You could use namespaces I suppose if you want some sort of behaviour like that. It won't work quite the way you want it but for example if you wrap `Public Module MyModule` in the namespace `Namespace Test` then you would have to access it `Test.MyModule` unless of course you wrap the other objects in the same namespace. Not sure if this would be what you're after though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, those need not be `Public` to get the global variable behavior.  `Friend` will also work:

> > The Friend keyword in the declaration statement specifies that the elements can be accessed from within the same assembly, but not from outside the assembly.

If you put your module in a different namespace, you can get the behavior you are after:

```
Namespace Plutonix
    Friend Module GlobalVars
        Friend MyVariable As Int32
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Unfortunately, VB will prepend the project Namespace to whatever you use so your import would be something like:

```
Imports PrjNamespace.Plutonix
```

But then you get what you are after:

```
GlobalVars.MyVariable = 9
```

Personally, I think the class version or as few global variables as possible is better

Comment: Note that in a way, the question is asking `How to prevent global variables from being globally accessed`.

Comment: `Friend` doesn't really help me here, as the issue is within a single assembly.

Comment: Yes, that part was addressing the notion that they need to be `Public` to be usable everywhere in the project.  They dont.  Adding a `Namespace` wrapper gets you more or less what you want

Comment: RE [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957520/prevent-public-module-variables-from-being-globally-accessible/46957994#comment80864422_46957994) -- There is an assumption here, that because this member is globally accessible, the member should be available project-wide using the unqualified name.

Comment: _Personally, I think the class version or as few global variables as possible is better_. This is the real answer to the question going forward. I completely agree. Global variables can become difficult to track throughout. Glad my namespace comment wasn't as far off as I initial thought.